# error in increase a variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

I've written this code to increase instance variable but it don't work and says:

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
class Ali
  @var1 = 2
  def initialize
  end

  def getvar1
    @var1 = @var1 + 2
    return @var1
  end
end
ali = Ali.new
puts ali.getvar1()
```

Comment: Time and time again we see this question. I need to find a good reference answer for dup-closing.

Answer (score 2):

Put your initial value `@var1 = 2` in the initializer. That's what initializers are for!

Answer (score 2):

You can do following to achieve what you want

```
class Ali
  def initialize
    @var1 = 2
  end

  def getvar1
    @var1 = @var1 + 2
  end
end

ali = Ali.new
ali.getvar1
=> 4
ali.getvar1
=> 6
```

Please note that in ruby `@var` is an instance variable and can only be accessed through an instance. `@@var` is a class variable which can be accessed anywhere in the class.

One more thing, last statement of a method is the default return value. Use explicit `return` only if the last statement is not the value you want as return value.